# How do you heal in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there a way besides Potions? Do pokemon restore health over time?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pokemon only restore health through the use of Potions of varying classes and Revives.

There is no mechanic for natural healing in the game yet.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently evolving heals Pokemon. Powering up does not - though it does increase their current health by the same amount as their increase in max health.

Comment: Powering up doesn't, except for the amount that your HP goes up.  (i.e., giving +2 HP to a 0/50 Pokemon will result in a 2/52 Pokemon)

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only way to heal is to get potions however me and some friends just trained up a gym and a lot of my Pokemon got hurt so many that I ran out of potions and there is no way to buy potions at the moment except for picking them up at pokestops just keep that in mind before training a gym

Answer (score 0):

Powering up doesn't heal them, sadly. Checked it earlier on my dragonite ^^;

Answer (score 0):

Only potions work right now. Go into your items, select a potion, and the Pokémon that it would effect will pop up. Select the Pokémon you want to heal. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there's no such thing like PokeCenter or healing of Pokemons automatically.

This is good for now as you don't have to battle for catching a wild Pokemon, and your Pokemon's health goes down only after battling.

So, the current options to heal your Pokemon are Potions, Super Potions, Max Potions to regain Pokemon's HP and Revive and Max Revive to heal a fainted Pokemon.

Comment: Hi Paras, please remember that any links or other sources you add to a post should actually be relevant to the point at hand. A general link to a wiki without context can be considered spam or unsolicited advertising, especially considering this isn't the first time you've linked to that particular wiki. I have removed this instance as it doesn't add anything to the answer

Comment: @Robotnik, sorry for that. I'll take care of that from next time.